# Automate login with selenium and python, how to correctly extract element for user and password

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, fitbit

I am trying to automate the login of a bunch of users to the fitbit site to download their data using the python's module selenium. Unfortunately I do not fully understand by looking at the source html code of the page, how to select the right elements.

My code looking something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://accounts.fitbit.com/login")

driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys('name.surname@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("myfakepass")
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
```

But I do not know how to extract the element since `driver.find_element_by_id("email")` returns the error:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("email")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="email"]
```

This makes totally sense to me since if I check the source page of https://accounts.fitbit.com/login I cannot detect any field called "email". But, probably due to my lack of experience, I cannot detect in the html source any of the elements that I need for the login.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **locator** seems wrong. Try with below `xpath`.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']"))).send_keys('name.surname@gmail.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']"))).send_keys("myfakepass")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Great! I had come up with a different code using the package time, but we your libraries this is not needed!

Answer (score 0):

There is a code that works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('your path')
url = "https://accounts.fitbit.com/login"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
email = driver.find_element_by_id("ember660")
email.send_keys("Edward@elric.com")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("ember661")
password.send_keys("Password")
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("ember701").click()
```

Your program didn't work because of the id which are wrong

Comment: thanks, using the chrome's command "inspect" I found different id though "ember659" for the email, and "ember660" for the password. Also I used the xpath for the login_button, otherwise it was not working

Comment: Yeah I just rode your code indeed we don't have the same id. That's weird because when I get to the website I still have the same Id

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple code that works.
It has been very useful to use the "Inspect" command integrated in chrome for finding the id or the xpath relative to each field. Also the package time was needed to avoid errors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path to chromedriver')
url = "https://accounts.fitbit.com/login"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
email = driver.find_element_by_id("ember659")
email.send_keys("mail@gmail.com")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("ember660")
password.send_keys('actualpassword')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[4]/div').click()
```